# Template constructor vs. non-template constructor in class any

Tags: c++

Imagine writing something like [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/any.html):

```
class any {
public:
  any();
  any(const any &);
  any(any &&);
  template<typename ValueType> any(const ValueType &);
  template<typename ValueType> any(ValueType &&);
```

Will the appropriate (copy/move) constructor be called for any possible `any`? Or does it have to be written with SFINAE e.g. like this:

```
template<typename ValueType,
  typename = typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_same<any, typename std::decay<ValueType>::type>::value
  >::type>
  any(const ValueType& value)
template<typename ValueType,
  typename = typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_same<any, typename std::decay<ValueType>::type>::value
  >::type>
  any(ValueType&& value)
```

**The question is:** Do I need to protect the templated constructor (to construct `any` from some value) or I can leave it, because the non-template (copy/move) constructor will always be matched for `any`? What about `volatile` modifier or some strange `std::move((const any&)it)` if that is possible?

Answer describing the search for the constructor will be most appriciated, thank you.

**EDIT:** Constructing `any` containing another `any` would be a problem, I definitelly want to avoid that (the SFINAE makes sure it cannot happen).

Comment: There is no need for both constructor templates. The second one is already using universal references.

Comment: @dyp: well, the const was not there in my question at first, but somebody had some complains ... about readability. Boost::any has them both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With C++11 and the introduction of *Universal Reference* (and a constructor with such parameter) the rules of overload resolution will choose the templated version.

The truth is that if the compiler can choose between templated and non-templated function, it will go with the non-template. But it will do so **only if they are equally good**:

> #### § 13.3.3 Best viable function `[over.match.best]`
>
> 1. [...] Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function
>      F2 if for all arguments *i*, ICS<sub>*i*</sub>(F1) is **not a worse** conversion sequence than ICS<sub>*i*</sub>(F2), and then
>
>    — for some argument *j*, ICS<sub>*j*</sub>(F1) is a **better conversion** sequence than ICS<sub>*j*</sub>(F2), or, **if not that**,
>
>    [...]
>
>    — F1 is a non-template function and F2 is a function template specialization, [...]

That said, having two constructors declared like below:

```
any(const any &);

template <typename ValueType>
any(const ValueType &);
```

the compiler will choose the **non-templated** version, as *instantiating* the templated one would result with **exactly same declaration**.

However, with the constructor taking *Unviersal Reference* the situation changes radically:

```
any(const any &);

template <typename ValueType>
any(ValueType &&);
```

In the context of to copying an instance with regular *direct-initialization* syntax:

```
any a;
any b{a};
```

the evaluated type of `a` is an lvalue `any &` **without** the `const` modifier. After generating the set of candidate constructors for overload resolution the compiler ends up with following signatures:

```
any(const any &); // non-template

any(any &); // instantiated template
```

And then:

> #### § 13.3.1 Candidate functions and argument lists `[over.match.funcs]`
>
> 7. In each case where a candidate is a function template, candidate function template specializations are generated using template argument deduction (14.8.3, 14.8.2). **Those candidates are then handled as candidate functions in the usual way.** A given name can refer to one or more function templates and also to a set of overloaded non-template functions. In such a case, the candidate functions generated from each function template are combined with the set of non-template candidate functions.

That is, the **template version is a better match**, and this is what the compiler chooses.

However, if one had:

```
const any a; // const!
any b{a};
```

Then this time the constructor signature generated from constructor taking *Universal Reference* would be the same as the non-template version of copy-constructor, so only then the **non-template** version is called.

> *What about volatile modifier or some strange std::move((const any&)it) if that is possible?*

Exactly the same happens. The *Universal Reference* constructor is **a better match.**

That is, `std::move((const any&)it)` evaluates to expression of `const any &&` type.

The parameter of non-template move constructor can take *non-const rvalue reference* (so does not match at all, since it lacks `const` modifier).

The parameter of non-template copy constructor can take the *const lvalue reference* (that is fine, const rvalue can be bound by const lvalue reference, but is **not an exact match**).

Then, the instantiated template taking *Universal Reference* is **again a better match that will be invoked.**

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I will likely accept it. My *bad feeling* about the templated constructor turned to be correct, thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, if a template and a non-template function are otherwise equally good matches, the non-template version is chosen over the template version. Since your `any` copy/move constructors are non-template, for rvalues or constant lvalues they take precedence over the template constructors.

**However** thanks due the special rules for rvalue reference templates, the deduced type for `template<typename ValueType> any(ValueType &&);` will be `any&` which is a *better* match. Therefore when copying a non-const lvalue, you'll call the templated constructor.

Therefore you need an SFINAE rule for that templated constructor, but not for the templated constructor taking an lvalue reference to const.

Comment: That is what I was thinking, thank you for clarification. Is it still good idea with SFINAE to prevent matching `volatile any` or whatever modification? In such case, the templated constructor could *possibly* by better match.

Comment: Ouch ... that's a side effect of the rvalue reference template rules I wasn't previously aware of ... I'll update my answer accordingly.